# How would one classify point groups?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, representation-theory, reflection, coxeter-groups

By [*point group*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_group) I mean a finit subgroup of $\mathrm O(\Bbb R^n)$.

Lists of point groups for some small dimensions are found on Wikipedia, but I am not certain about their completeness. As there seem to exist lists, I wonder the following:

> **Question:** How would one go about classifying the point groups in some fixed dimension $n$?

I know that all (finite) [*reflection groups*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_group) can be listed systematically via *Coxeter diagrams*, but not all point groups are reflection groups $-$ in fact, they are not even subgroups of reflection groups as explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/916327/415941).

Can the classification of point groups be obtained from the classification of reflection groups in some simple way, e.g. by only taking products and subgroups?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "classify". Every finite group embeds in some permutation group, hence, in some $O(n)$, and we do not even have names for all finite groups. In contrast, finite simple groups are classified. If you are asking about these, then it becomes a rather difficult question of representation theory of these groups which is a vast area of research.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I know that every group is *isomorphic* to a point group. This is why I asked about classification for a *fixed dimension $n$*. I am also less interested in the actual list of point groups, but more in the methods and tools used to find it: how to know that I found all, or how to construct more. I am specifically interested in the mentioned connection between point groups and reflection groups. E.g. explaining to me that every point group can be obtained from a reflection group in some simple way would be a helpful answer. In fact, this was told to me. But is it true?

Comment: I do not know what a "simple way" would mean. Take a look here for references etc:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37136/classification-of-finite-groups-of-isometries One more thing to know is Jordan-Schur theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Schur_theorem